# Filesystem set to read only frequently Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: filesystem, hardware, 18.10, drive, read-only

In the past few days my system repeats to set itself to read only.
I've done some searches and apparently my drive might have gone bad? After a reboot I've been running fsck and say yes to everything and it works again for something between 24 and 48 hours.

Judging from my google searches the output of dmesg seems to be important:

```
[ 9563.932564] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_iget:4831: inode #26092049: comm dockerd: bad extra_isize 28448 (inode size 256)
[ 9563.933915] Aborting journal on device sda1-8.
[ 9563.935159] EXT4-fs (sda1): Remounting filesystem read-only
[ 9563.935211] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_iget:4831: inode #26092049: comm dockerd: bad extra_isize 28448 (inode size 256)
```

Also this is my smartctl output for the drive, which also has been asked for in some threads:

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.19.5-041905-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     SAMSUNG MZ7LN512HMJP-000L7
Serial Number:    S2X9NX0HA05931
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 d00000000
Firmware Version: MAV01L6Q
User Capacity:    512.110.190.592 bytes [512 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4c
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Dec 26 00:42:12 2018 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        No Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (  85) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       2723
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       3557
170 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0033   099   099   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       7
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       260
178 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Chip  0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
180 Unused_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot 0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       1621
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0032   072   049   000    Old_age   Always       -       28 (Min/Max 14/51)
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   084   084   000    Old_age   Always       -       15678
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0013   099   099   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       16679347
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       4393
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       7996
249 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       4393

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      2712         -
# 2  Offline             Completed without error       00%      2398         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
  255        0    65535  Read_scanning was never started
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

I do sometimes not correctly shutdown my notebook. Sometimes its stuck after closing and reopening the lid so I need to force shutdown and generally I try to reboot as little as possible so most of my reboots in the past week might very well have been force shutodwn -> start again. I suppose this could very well corrupt the filesystem although it shouldn't destroy my ssd, should it?

I'd be very thankful if someone could help me with this. If my drive is bad I'm just going to buy a new one but since it's only 2 years old that seems rater unlikely to me.

edit:
Okay apparently there is some problem with the ubuntu 4.19 kernel which I was using because my kernel version crashed the system whenever I started a java application. I updated to 4.20 now will report back in a few days if I still experience read-only or not!

https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=EXT4-Linux-4.19-Corruption

Comment: Forcing a shutdown when the filesystems are mounted read-write (`rw`) will most likely corrupt them, or at least leave them marked as "dirty". I don't know what "ext4_iget:4831: inode #26092049: comm dockerd: bad extra_isize 28448 (inode size 256)" means, I'd search the web for it (maybe without the specific numbers)

Comment: Blaming kernel 4.19 *which is in testing* seems willfully blind several ways. First, testing feedback needs to flow through bug reports and dev channels, not here. AskUbuntu is support for released software only. If you didn't volunteer to be a tester, then you have a very different problem than you thought. Second, there are proper shutdown techniques to use when "stuck". Look up 'REISUB' and similar. Learn them and make then your habit. Finally, investigate your stuck-on-wakeup problem - most systems don't do that.

Comment: @user535733 Honstely I'm not very deep into all the linux/unix/ubuntu stuff. I just wanted to run neo4j which made my pc freeze completely. I researched that and people said it's a problem with older linux kernels. So I updated my Kernel to the newest available version, which fixed my problem yay! I mean arguably a system not being able to run java is less useful than a read only system for some people so what difference does it make if I use an older version that is not in testing anymore but still has such a huge problem? MIght as well use the newest one.
Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: Yes, kernel 4.19 is supposed to have some corruption issues. But so does some older Samsung SSD's. Check for firmware updates at the Samsung web site. See https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/